# Adding drawable resource using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I want to add a drawable resource to my cordova project. I did add the icon and splashscreen items just fine. They get copied to my platform/android/res/drawable just fine. The problem is when I try to add another resource. How do I do that? I can't find anything on cordova rather than icon and splashscreen

```
<platform name="android">
<icon src="xx.png" density="ldpi"/>
<icon src="xx.png" density="mdpi"/>
<icon src="xx.png" density="hdpi"/>
<icon src="xx.png" density="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="xx.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
<icon src="xx.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
<splash src="xx.png" density="ldpi"/>
<splash src="xx.png" density="mdpi"/>
<splash src="xx.png" density="hdpi"/>
<splash src="xx.png" density="xhdpi"/>
<splash src="xx.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
<splash src="xx.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
```

Can somebody help there? I don't see any option in the config.xml to add other drawable resources.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and describe the "hook" solution?  I'm not sure how to implement that and have the same issue as your original post.

Answer (score 19):

EDIT:

Since Cordova CLI 7.x.x, when using cordova-android 6.2.x or cordova-ios 4.4.x you can use the resource-file tag from config.xml as I explained for on my old answer for plugins. You have to put it inside the platform tag.

Example:

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="www/res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png" />
</platform>
```

src is where you have the image right now, could be in www as in my example or even in the root of the project if you don't want the file duplicated. 
target is the destination, it will be in yourProject/platforms/platform/target
for the example it would be `yourProject/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png`

OLD answer:

From the config.xml you can only add icons and launch images

If you want to add a resource you can create a plugin and use the `resource-file` tag

```
<resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png" />
```

Or you can use a hook that copies the image to wherever you want

Comment: I went for the hook option. looks cleaner and have all logic in gulpfile

Comment: please give more explanations, it's too vague

Comment: for the plugin read https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file, for the hook, see sinedied answer

Comment: @jcesarmobile this works for me with Cordova CLI 6.5.0 and cordova-android 6.3.x :thumbsup:

Comment: Ah, then maybe cordova-android 6.2.0 or greater is enough

Answer (score 4):

For the next people like me, here is my simple hook to do this, to put in `hooks/before_build/020_copy_resources.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Copy native resources
var rootdir = process.argv[2];
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Native resources to copy
var androidNativePath = 'native/android/';

// Android platform resource path
var androidResPath = 'platforms/android/res/';

function copyAndroidResources() {
  exec('cp -Rf ' + androidNativePath + '* ' + androidResPath);
  process.stdout.write('Copied android native resources');
}

if (rootdir) {
  copyAndroidResources();
}
```

Just put your android resources in `native/android/` then and you're good to go.

Comment: This worked like a charm, but make sure you follow the sub-folder naming convention for the res folder for files in native/android/.